# Подбор значений аргумента в линейной функции

Tags: python

Имеется стандартная функция `y=a*x+b`. Имеются фиксированные значения коэффициентов a и b, изменяться должно только значение аргумента `x+=1`. В моем понимании для начала нужно установить функцию, определить значения аргументов и с помощью цикла **while** начать перебирать значение **x**, увеличивая его на +1.

```
def y():
    global x
    x=1
    a=2
    b=4 
    return a*x+b
while y()<=100:
    print("значение аргумента x = ", x,"значение функции y = ", y())
    x+=1
```

Результат выглядит следующим образом:

```
значение аргумента x =  1 значение функции y =  6
значение аргумента x =  1 значение функции y =  6
Process finished with exit code -1
```

В чем заключается ошибка? как изменить бесконечный цикл так чтобы значения **x** всё таки перебирались, пока **y** не достигнет 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Быстрая правка — используйте `x` как параметр функции:

```
def y(x):
    a = 2
    b = 4 
    return a * x + b

x = 1
while y(x) <= 100:
    print("значение аргумента x = ", x,"значение функции y = ", y(x))
    x += 1
```

Лучшее решение (изменение только второй части):

```
def y(x):
    a = 2
    b = 4 
    return a * x + b

for x in range(1, 101):
    print(f"значение аргумента x = {x:3}, значение функции y = {y(x):3}")
```

Число `3` за двоеточием в последней команде выделяет число позиций для выведенного числа, в рамках которых оно будет выровнено вправо (для красивого вывода):

> ```
> значение аргумента x =   1, значение функции y =   6
> значение аргумента x =   2, значение функции y =   8
> значение аргумента x =   3, значение функции y =  10
>                  ................
>                  ................
> значение аргумента x =  98, значение функции y = 200
> значение аргумента x =  99, значение функции y = 202
> значение аргумента x = 100, значение функции y = 204
> ```

Comment: у первого и второго решения вроде бы разные выводы

Comment: @RockInMyHead, вы внимательны, да, первые решение ограничивает `y`, пока второе ограничивает `x`. Но я хотел показать и такую возможность. Спасибо вам.